# Title bar completely unresponsive

Tags: raspbian

I went into the Openbox settings and messed round with the theme, but then reverted it back to what it was. Now, the minimize, maximize, and x buttons don't work. When I hover over them, they show the animations and stuff, but they do't do anything. What's more, since the title bar doesn't work at all, I can't even drag windows. I don't know what's wrong, please help.

Answer (score 2):

The Openbox Menu doesn't work on the Pi.

Two years ago I got a rather [scathing reply](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1404762#p1404762) from one of the Raspberry Pi Engineers for using it.

Apparently it is broken and they have no intention of fixing it, or providing an alternative tool. (This is a consequence of one of Simon Long's fiddles with the Raspberry Pi OS GUI.)

You could try editing `.config/openbox/` files or restoring from another installation.

If you select one of the preferred options in `Appearance Settings` `Defaults`  this should reset to defaults.

PS I keep a copy of `.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml` so I can restore settings if one of the updates breaks it.

Comment: Where is the `.config/openbox/` folder?

Comment: The only place it would make sense - in your home directory. Normally only contains `.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml`

Comment: If the file doesn't exist you can copy from `/etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml`

Comment: My Pi's microSD card got corrupted so I had to reflash Raspbian, so now everything is naturally back to normal.